# Node js put schemas in other folder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have created basic node project in which i created model folder inside model folder i have schema folder and index.js

in schema folder have all schema of my project and in index.js i write some thing like this

```
var s1 = require('./schema/schema1');
var s2 = require('./schema/schema2');


module.export = function(app) {
    schema1= s1 ;
    schema2= s2 ;
}
```

and in controller file i m accessing model like this

```
    var model = require('./models/');

    model.schema1.find(function(err, data) {
    })
```

but this above code not working its give me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` but when i try something like this in controller

```
var schema1= require('../models/schema/schema1');
schema1.find(function(err,data){});
```

its working fine but i want 1st structure in my project i using mongoose, express, node, mongodb.

Please help i don't know what i m doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index.js` exports a function returning nothing. Either do:

```
var s1 = require('./schema/schema1');
var s2 = require('./schema/schema2');

module.exports = function (app) {
    return {
        schema1: s1,
        schema2: s2
    }
}
```

Then require like this: `var model = require('./models/')();` (notice the (), it's a function, you must call it to get the returned object).

Or, if you don't use the `app` parameter at all:

```
var s1 = require('./schema/schema1');
var s2 = require('./schema/schema2');

module.exports = {
    schema1: s1,
    schema2: s2
}
```

Then you can simply `var model = require('./models/');` (no () here)).

You also had a typo on *module.export**s***, you forgot the `s`.

Answer (score 0):

pass your Schema to second file do something like this in first file :

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    // my props
});
require('./app/anotherFolder.js')(mySchema)
```